# How to exchange specific rows of values between two columns in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

For instance:

```
col1 col2
1    0
1    0
1    0
1    0
1    0
1    0
1    0
1    0
1    0
```

We change the table above into the following:

```
col1 col2
1    0
1    0
1    0
0    1
0    1
0    1
1    0
1    0
1    0
```

Which means we exchange the values between col1 and col2 in rows 4-6.

Any one has some ideas how to achieve it through R code?

Comment: Sure, make a variable that determines which rows. Then use that variable to subset data from individual column. Assign values to opposite columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `rev` to exchanging two columns for specific rows like:

```
i <- 4:6    #Rows
j <- c(1,2) #Columns
x[i,j] <- x[i,rev(j)]
x
#  col1 col2
#1    1    0
#2    1    0
#3    1    0
#4    0    1
#5    0    1
#6    0    1
#7    1    0
#8    1    0
#9    1    0
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(col1=rep(1, 9), col2=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

To swap row 4-6 from `col1` to `col2` and from `col2` to `col1` you could use this base formula:

```
df[4:6,1:2] <- df[4:6,2:1]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
1    1    0
2    1    0
3    1    0
4    0    1
5    0    1
6    0    1
7    1    0
8    1    0
9    1    0
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), col2 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```